# Value can not be null. parameter name "key" on DataRowView's EndEdit() Method

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm using DataTable as a Source of GridView. while creating datarow's to the datatable, all column's are assigned and the value can not be null exception been thrown on setting item source.

any help would be helpful.
thanks,
Sarathi

Comment: Could you show the complete stack trace, please?

Answer (score 1):

I guess adding following key in your web.config should solve the issue.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
  <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Also you can disable compilation on debug using following

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I see no sign that this has anything to do with web applications - the question is talking about WPF. (It's not clear how this answer would be related to the issue in the question anyway, to be honest.)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i am getting this error in a WPF desktop application. not a web application.

Comment: sorry. in a hurry I misunderstood.